# Leaflet maxBounds doesn't prevent zooming out

Tags: leaflet, extents

In Leaflet 1.0.2, if you set `maxBounds` on a map, it prevents panning beyond those bounds, but does not prevent zoom out beyond them. Is this by design? It seems incorrect behaviour to me. I need to prevent display of the map beyond given bounds, and thought `maxBounds` would do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design, or rather said, by default. The devs (me included) thought "well, users already have `minZoom` to prevent this kind of thing", so the focus was on making sure that the `maxBounds` were always visible when zoomed out.

As a workaround, you might want to run something like:

```
 map.setMinZoom( map.getBoundsZoom( map.options.maxBounds ) );
```

Be aware that this might change if the map container is resized.

Answer (score 3):

As another workaround, I used the properties said in [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/)!, especifically that the width or height of the world is  `256*Math.pow(2, zoomLevel)` pixels.

Then, considering that the width and height of the map can be caught through javascript (`clientWidth` and `clientHeight`), the `minZoom` to not show beyond the bounds would be:

```
minZoom = Math.ceil(Math.log2(Math.max(width, height) / 256))
```

Which is just a development of the previous formula used with the map's width and height to find a `minZoom` value.